# How to change default image in Django

Tags: django

I have a django app that allows users to fill out a form, and attach an image if they like. If they decide not to attach an image, I want a default image in it's place. The problem is that when the user tries to attach an image during the post creation, it doesn't save. It only saves when the post is edited.

**model field:**

`image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default = 'noImageAttached.png')`

This works as expected when a user creates a new post and does not add a new image. The default image 'noImageAttached.png' is used.
However, when someone wants to attach an image in the`CreateView` it will not throw any errors, it just will simply not save the image. 
When this same post is edited with `UpdateView`, you can upload an image, and it works. Something in my `CreateView` is causing it to not work? Or maybe there is a different way of using `default` in models.py?

**views.py**

```
class assetCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Assets
    form_class = Asset_Creation_Form
    template_name = 'addAsset.html'
    login_url = 'login'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    #these fields are hidden from user, and filled out automatically
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.createdBy = (self.request.user.first_name)+ " "+ (self.request.user.last_name)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**forms.py**

```
class Asset_Creation_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Assets
        fields = ('assetMake', 'assetModel', 'assetDescription', 'assetSerialNo',
            'assetDescription','programID','programOwner','category','condition',
            'location','dateAquired','purchasePrice','image','createdBy',)
```

**addAsset.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block body %}
  <h1>Add New Asset</h1>
  <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  <button class="btn btn-success ml-2" type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: add the code of your Asset_Creation_Form and HTML.

Comment: Added form and html :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` inside your form tag.

For eg.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: That did it, thank you. Do you mind briefly explaining why this worked?

Comment: it is HTML related, if you want to upload file, you need to set enctype="multipart/form-data".  [Docs Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)